# Solve without using L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to solve this without using L'Hôpital's rule?

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \Big(\frac{3x+1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\Big)
$$

I tried to solve it but I got stuck at the $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ part.

$$
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3+x^{-1}}{1}-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sin x}
$$

since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sin x}$  does not exist.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x^{-1}$ doesn't exist either.

Comment: You cannot take the limit of the two terms separately. Instead combine them into one fraction. At some point you will need to find $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and don't think there is any way to do this without L'Hopital's rule (or the definition of derivative of $\sin$ at the origin) without rederiving the limit from first principles --- see any Calculus textbook.

Comment: For what it's worth: We have $\dfrac1{x}-\dfrac1{\sin x}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1}{x}\cdot\dfrac{x}{\sin x}=\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{f(x)},$ where $f$ is the [sinc function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$, $x\neq 0$, $f(0)=1$. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$, and the limit of a product is the product of the limits, the limit of the expression above is $0$.  (But this only reduces the problem to showing that $f'(0)$ exists. If we know that $f'(0)$ exists it follows from oddness that $f'(0)=0$.)

Comment: @JonasMeyer - This is getting more complicated than I expected...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Via power series

$$\frac{3x+1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}=\frac{3x\sin x+\sin x-x}{x\sin x}=$$

$$\frac{3x\left(x-O(x^3)\right)+\left(x-O(x^3)\right)-x}{x\left(x-O(x^3)\right)}=\frac{3x^2-O(x^4)-O(x^3)}{x^2-O(x^4)}=$$

$$3\frac{1-O(x^2)-O(x)}{1-O(x^2)}\xrightarrow [x\to 0]{}3\cdot 1=3$$

Comment: Which book do I need to read in order to acquire familiarity with the magic of big O manipulation?

Answer (score 6):

When $x\ne 0$, our function is equal to
$$3-\left(\frac{x-\sin x}{x\sin x}\right).$$
So we want to find 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x\sin x}.$$
This limit is obviously $0$ (look at the Maclaurin series of $\sin x$). But presumably if L'Hospital's Rule is forbidden, then Maclaurin series are also forbidden.

We consider positive $x$ only, since if we deal with these, what happens for negative $x$ is clear by symmetry.

We need to know something about the behaviour of $x-\sin x$ for positive $x$ near $0$.

$1$. First we show that $x\ge \sin x$ if $x\ge 0$. Let $f(x)=x-\sin x$. Note that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)=1-\cos x\ge 0$, so $f(x)$ is non-decreasing for positive $x$. It follows that $f(x)\ge 0$ if $x\ge 0$.

$2$. Next we show that $\cos x\ge 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x\ge 0$. Let $g(x)=\cos x-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$. Note that $g(0)=0$ and, by the result of $(1)$, $g'(x)=-\sin x+x\ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$. It follows that $g(x)\ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$.

$3$. Next we show that $\sin x\ge x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ for $x\ge 0$. Let $h(x)=\sin x-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)$. We have $h(0)=0$, and by the result of $(2)$, $h'(x)\ge 0$ if $x\ge 0$. The desired result follows.

We conclude thaat if $x\ge 0$, then $0\le x-\sin x\le \frac{x^3}{6}$. From this inequality, it follows easily that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x\sin x}=0$.

**Remark:** Any proof **must** address the behaviour of $x-\sin x$ near $0$. Of course we do not need the very strong $|x-\sin x|\le \frac{x^3}{6}$ that we obtained above. But we must show at least that $|x-\sin x|=o(x^2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a hint which uses no L'Hôpital, no derivatives, and no power series; just trigonometry.

**Hint:** In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151), it is shown, geometrically, that $\sin(x)\le x\le\tan(x)$ for $x\in[0,\pi/2)$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\,\right|
&=\left|\,\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x\sin(x)}\,\right|\\
&\le\left|\,\frac{\sin(x)-\tan(x)}{x\sin(x)}\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\frac{1-\sec(x)}{x}\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\frac{1-\sec(x)}{x}\frac{1+\sec(x)}{1+\sec(x)}\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\frac{1-\sec^2(x)}{x(1+\sec(x))}\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\frac{-\tan^2(x)}{x(1+\sec(x))}\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\frac{\tan(x)}{1+\sec(x)}\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\tan(x/2)\,\right|
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x - x}{x^2}$. Replacing $x$ by $2y$, we obtain:

$
\begin{align*}
L & = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin 2y - 2y}{4y^2} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{2 \sin y \cos y - 2y}{4y^2} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{2 \sin y \cos y - 2 \sin y + 2 \sin y - 2y}{4y^2} \\
& = \lim_{y \to 0} \left( \frac{2 \sin y(\cos y-1)}{4y^2}+\frac{1}{2} \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin y - y}{y^2}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{y \to 0} \sin y \cfrac{-2\sin^2\cfrac{y}{2}}{y^2}+\frac{1}{2}L \\ 
& = -\frac{1}{4} \lim_{y \to 0} \sin y \cfrac{\sin^2\cfrac{y}{2}}{\cfrac{y^2}{4}}+\frac{1}{2}L, 
\end{align*}
$

which implies that $L=0$.

Hence,

$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{3x+1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right) & = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(3+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(3+\frac{\sin x - x}{x \sin x}\right) \\
& = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(3+\frac{\sin x - x}{x^2} \cdot \frac{x}{\sin x} \right) = 3+0 \cdot 1 \\ 
& = \boxed{3},
\end{align*}
$

Comment: This assumes that the limit $L$ exists.  How do you know this is true?

Comment: @Antonio Vargas. You are correct. I also notice that one. Unless $L$ is guaranteed to be finite, then nothing to be worried.

Answer (score -2):

Here is another approach since we know

$$
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{3x+1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sin x}\right) \\
&\qquad = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(3 +\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sin x}\right) \\
&\qquad = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(3 + \frac{\sin x - x}{x\sin x}\right) \\
&\qquad = 3 + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x - x}{x\sin x}
\end{align*}
$$

now lets divide the top and bottom by $x^2$ to get

$$3  + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\sin x - x)/x^2}{x\sin x/x^2} = 3 + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\sin x - x)/x^2}{\sin x/x}$$

now using the $lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ we could apply this to the denominator now obtaining

$$= 3 + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x - x}{x^2}$$ now lets break the last term up

alright so after we can break this up into

$$\lim_{x\to 0} [(\sin x/x)(1/x) - (1/x) ]$$
now if we factor out $1/x$ we obtain

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x)[(\sin x/x) - 1 ]$$
now lets apply limit property to this to obtain
$$\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x)*\lim_{x\to 0}[(\sin x/x) - 1 ]$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x)*\lim_{x\to 0}[1 - 1 ] = \lim_{x\to 0} (1/x)*0 = 0$$

so $$3 + 0 = 3$$

:D

now i did not break no calculus rule, sorry its not in latex form still learning a little bit

Comment: @Hamza. Remember that$\frac{\sin x}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}\neq \frac{\sin x}{x}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Comment: @Hamza. The last part of your computations seems not correct to me.

Comment: @Derek: Unfortunately, it is not.  Look closer...

Comment: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ This is too complicated

Comment: This is still wrong... $\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x$ doesn't exist, so you can't say that $$\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x)(\sin x/x - 1) = \left(\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x\right)\left(\lim_{x\to 0} (\sin x/x-1)\right).$$

Answer (score -3):

alright so lets break up the first term to get

lim(x->0) [3x/x + 1/x - 1/sinx] 
now lets use properties of limits

lim(x->0) 3 + lim(x->0) (1/x) - lim(x->0) 1/sinx
now knowing that lim(x->0) sinx/x = 1 lets divide the third term by x at the numerator as well as the denominator to obtain

lim(x->0) 3 + lim(x->0) (1/x) - lim(x->0) (1/x)/sinx/x

and since the denominator is just 1 we are left with

lim(x->0) 3 + lim(x->0) (1/x) - lim(x->0) (1/x)

BUT notice lim x--> 0 1/x does not exist. so this direct method of finding limit would not work. another use is power series as one of the answer is posted :)

Comment: This is wrong for the same reasons that the other answer is wrong.  Replace $\sin x$ with $x+x^2$ and try to use the same method to find that limit.  It fails; your steps are not valid.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{x}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{\sin x}$ do not exist.

Comment: So you can't subtract two limits that does not exist?

Comment: sure you can man what are you talking about Antonio and Jonas, take an analogy for an example you have an apple you add a random ugly fruit but then you subtract the ugly fruit. lol

Comment: No Hamza, what are *you* talking about?  Try calculating $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3x+1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+x^2}$$ using this method.

Comment: thats not what the question  states, you are changing the whole question

Comment: The "justifications" you use in each step also apply to that question.  If they were valid, they would give you the correct answer there too, but they don't.  You get the right answer for the original question on accident.

Comment: @Hamza You are totally wrong with your concept. Remember that limit of the quotient exists provided that both the limit of the numerator and limit of the denominator(not zero) exist. In your case, for the third term, the limit of the numerator does not exist.

Comment: yeah you are right. my fault. it was a fluke that i got that answer i see what you guys are  talking about